# Using sed to show C style comment and C++ comment

Tags: linux, unix, sed, command-line, stream

so far I did this but it does not print what I want it to. Thank you in advance.

```
$  sed -n -e "/\(*\)/g" c_comments | sed -n '/\/\*/p; /^ \*/p' c_comments |sed -n '/[[:blank:]]/p' c_comments
```

This is the text file c_comments, and I want to extract the c_style comment and C++ comments.
    // File with various examples of C and C++ style comments

```
/* simple C style comment on one line with no code  */

x = 5*3;   /* Example comment following code   */

   /* comments do not have to begin at the line beginning  */
/*  And you can have empty comments like the next one */
/**/
/*  comments with code following the comment  (not possible with C++ style) 
*/  x = w * u/y/z;
  // As shown below you can have what appear to comments embedded in a 
 string
    // The line below should be counted as code
printf(" This output string looks like a /* comment */ doesn't it?\n"); 
/* ---- Example of a multiline 
C style comment  */       
c++;  //  C ++ style comment following code
c=a/b*c;   /*  comment between two pieces of code */   w = a*b/e;
 /*  This is a multiline c style comment.  This
comment covers several
lines.
 ------*/
a = b / c * d;
/* -----------End of the file ---------------*/
```

Comment: If you're piping input to `sed` you shouldn't give it a filename argument. When it gets a filename argument it ignores the standard input.

Comment: You can use one `sed` command with multiple `-e` options to perform several different operations.

Comment: C and C++ both use the same commenting style. What do you think the difference is?

Comment: so what you suggesting? do u mean to use the file name only once

Comment: well, c_style editing is /* this is C style comment */ where         C++ commenting is //  this is c++ comment

Comment: C added `//` comments many years ago.

Comment: I'm suggesting `sed <operation> filename | sed <operation> | sed <operation>`. You would do this if you want the second `sed` to filter the output of the first one.

Comment: But if they should all process the whole file, it should be `sed -e <operation> -e <operation> -e <operation> filename`

Comment: so something like this,                                                                                                
      sed -e "/\(*\)/g" c_comments | sed -e '/\/\*/p; /^ \*/p'  | sed -e '/[[:blank:]]/p'

Comment: yeah. I also don't understand what you mean by `"/\(*\)/g"`. Should that be `p` instead of `g`?

Comment: You also need to escape `*` to match it literally.

Comment: But if you only print lines containing `*`, you won't get `//` comments.

Comment: Note that `sed` regexps can help you find some comments, but not all of them. The C/C++ syntax is of a more complex class of languages than what regexps can parse. CS people know the theoretical explanation.

Comment: $  sed  "/\(*\)/g" c_comments              this gives the following output                                                                                                      // File with various examples of C and C++ style comments









      // As shown below you can have what appear to comments embedded in a string
        // The line below should be counted as code



 c++;  //  C ++ style comment following code


    comment covers several
    lines.

Answer (score 3):

The following will process your *particular* file.

```
#! /bin/sed -f

# using ':' for regex delimiter, as we are matching a lot of
# literal '/' in the following expressions

# remove quoted strings
# TODO: allow quotes in comments and detect multiline quoted strings
s:["][^"]*["]::g

# detect '/* ... */'
\:/\*.*\*/: {
    # handle leading '//'
    \://.*/\*: {
        s:.*//://:
        p;d
    }
    s:.*/\*:/*:
    s:\*/.*:*/:
    p;d
}

# detect '/* ... \n ... */'
# TODO: fix the '// ... /*' case
\:/\*:,\:\*/: {
    s:.*/\*:/*:
    s:\*/.*:*/:
    p;d
}

# detect //
\://: {
    s:.*//://:
    p;d
}
d
```

The above is more of a non-example than an example -- to show some of the things that are really difficult to do in **sed** (pay special attention to the `TODO`'s).

So, in general, extracting C comments using a single **sed** script is IMO not such a good fit -- getting it to be altogether correct would be very hard and the result would very quickly devolve into some very obtuse code.

Here is an alternative that decorates our C Source with **sed**, uses **awk** to filter it (taking into account the multi-level C syntax rules), and then removes decoration again with **sed**:

**c_decorate**

```
#! /bin/sed -f
s:\r::g
s:/\*:\rC/*:g
s:\*/:*/\rE:g
s://:\rL//:g
s:":\rQ":g
```

**c_filter**

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    RS = ORS = "\r"
    lc=0 # State variable for continuing a C++ style Line comment
    cc=0 # State variable for continuing a C style comment
    qt=0 # quote-count
}

NR == 1 { print ""; next }

/^C/ { # Begin C-Style Comment
    if (qt % 2)
        next
    if (lc) {
        if ($0 ~ /\n/) {
            lc = 0
            sub(/\n.*/, "\n")
        }
    } else {
        cc = 1
    }
    print
    next
}
/^E/ { # End C-Style Comment
    if (qt % 2)
        next
    if (lc) {
        if ($0 ~ /\n/) {
            lc = 0
            sub(/\n.*/, "\n")
        }
        print 
    } else if (cc) {
        cc = 0
        if ($0 ~ /\n/)
            print "\n"
        else
            print "E"
    }
    next    
}
/^L/ { # Begin C++ Style Line Comment
    if (qt % 2)
        next
    if (!cc) {
        lc = 0
        if ($0 ~ /\n/)
            sub(/\n.*/, "\n")
        else
            lc = 1
    }
    print
    next
}
/^Q/ { # Quote
    if (lc || cc)
        print
    else
        qt++
    next
}
```

**c_cleanup**

```
#! /bin/sed -f
$ {
    /^$/ d
}
s:\r[CELQ]\?::g
```

And to call:

```
$ c_decorate c_comments | c_filter | c_cleanup
```

**Awk** fits more naturally then **sed** for filtering because it natively supports the change of record separator, and it is much easier to specify and reason about arbitrary logic relationships.

To get rid of comment tags, here is an alternative version of **c_decorate**:

```
#! /bin/sed -f
s:\r::g
s:/\*:\rC:g
s:\*/:\rE:g
s://:\rL:g
s:":\rQ":g
```

Update 9/2019 (@Russ) This does not appear to process "quotes" in comments very well, or C-style comments embedded in C++ one line comments, as in

```
//* this is not handled well.  
/* nor "is" this. */
```

Therefore, I used this for c_decorate:

```
#! /bin/sed -f
s:\r::g
# trouble is //* first matches //, then matches /*
s:[^/]/\*:\rC/*:g
s:^/\*:\rC/*:g
s:\*/:*/\rE:g
s://\+:\rL&:g
# does not handle quotes w/in comments
# s:":\rQ":g
```

Comment: This is very good, but it gets confused on some "//" forms.  I think it fails on a // followed by a double quote in the comment, e.g., // "foo" is what we want - in that case, it flips a bit and starts including non-commented code immediately following.

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -n -e '/^[[:space:]]*\/\//p' -e ' /^[[:space:]]*\/\*.*\*\/[[:space:]]*$/p' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/p' c_comments
```